# I need to ask a question which primarily concerns professional views on the subject

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

> I am relatively new to PHP security implementations. So, I had a
>   question :  Can I have the complete listings of possible ways to hack a
>   PHP website or webapp?
>
> I've learned many solutions on the subject. And I'm not asking for the
>   methods to overcome these 'possibilities'. I'm trying to understand
>   what are the features available in the PHP website and its servers
>   that might cause a security blip, which then I can find a workaround
>   or solution for, by myself. The level of security might be low, since I'm a
>   novice in security. But I need to cover all possible ways to secure it.
>
> For example:
>
> ### URL
>
> 1. A URL could be used to access a file from the server, which the user
>      should not have access to, if the URL itself is not manipulated to
>      authenticate the download.
> 2. Parameters passed through a URL could be
>      edited by the user, So proper validation is required when using
>      these values.
> 3. ...etc...

This is a neither a *personal opinion* question, nor a *code oriented* question. This is a technical discussion question, which must result in a pitch perfect list. ***Where am I supposed to ask such a question in the Stack Exchange network?***

(I found a similar question on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11234/how-does-hacking-work), but it was said to be out of topic)

Comment: I've rolled back to remove the request for a reference work on security. Such requests are off-topic on the main site. The fact that we don't have a dedicated close reason for them on Meta does not imply that they *are* on-topic for Meta.

Comment: Why are you guys not reading the questions?! I said "I needed to ask for a reference. And wanted to know where I should ask that question'." I didn't ask it in here.

Comment: @Louis "EDIT: If this method is not possible, can I ask for a solid reference that I could read, which covers the maximum of this subject? If so where should I ask it?" Do you even know the difference between CAN and MAY?

Comment: Yes, I know the difference. I also know that, as a matter of pragmatics, not all speakers make the distinction. I also know that, again as a matter of pragmatics, asking "can I ask X" or "may I ask X" amounts to asking X.

Answer (score 15):

This question really wouldn't fit well *anywhere* on the Stack Exchange network. We're set up to answer very specific questions, and not list questions. For a good explanation on this, see [List questions: Community Wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki):

> Asking everyone to contribute to a large bucket of answers means that
>   it stops being a question of *specific expertise* and becomes a "poll"
>   of the community. For right or for wrong, answer start accumulating
>   and people start voting on what they recognize as familiar, rather
>   than vetting the relative merits of each answer. Often there are too
>   many entries to even know what anyone is contributing anymore. It
>   doesn't even matter; There's usually no expectation that any one
>   answer will be better than any other.
>
> What I am saying is that the Big List<sup>™</sup> breaks down
>   the whole premise of why we created these sites in the first place
>   — to vet and deem the information contained in the post as
>   *useful*.

While there have been some attempts to break this mold (see for example [the "collaborative effort" lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311672/best-practices-of-building-a-website-using-node-js)), most Stack Exchange sites try to stay away from these types of questions.

Additionally, what you're asking for doesn't seem very useful -- there's so many ways you can "break into" a website, and a lot of them depend very much on what you do (Do you accept user input? Do you store user input? etc). And, of course, there's always a possibility of a vulnerability no one except for the "bad guys" know of.

Comment: I knew the list would be long and might even comprise a whole article on the subject. I also expected this question might be down-voted. but I had no other options... I've searched a lot on the web, where none of them seems to cover the advanced security part. Most of what I've read have already been implemented by me for the website I'm working on...

Comment: @BlackPanther I don't know much about security, so I'm afraid I can't help you here. There's probably some pentesting applications & books about this topic, but again, not sure...

Comment: The fact that you have no other options or searched a lot on the web means nothing in terms of being on topic on one of the stack exchange sites. @BlackPanther

Comment: @PeeHaa For the sake of future reference, I would like to know how that question is off topic. 
"Meta is for Stack Overflow users to communicate with each other about Stack Overflow (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)" - as quoted on the help page.

Comment: That question was a question about the policy stackoverflow follows. I just wanted to know, where would stackoverflow want me to post that question.

Comment: @BlackPanther hichris123 summed up *why* your question is offtopic.